# Information XML convert to XMI

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xmi

I create a program to scan one database special.

I get information like name of the class name of attribute and i all stocked in XML, and i want to get a graphs of those information to give me a visibility of the database.

My XML likes this :

```
 <Zone OrdreZone="4" Redifinies="">
        <InfoCommon Niveau="7" Name="MyName1."/>
        <Attribut Type="Int" Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="20">
            <InfoCommon Niveau="10" Name="XXXXXX"/>
        </Attribut>
        <Attribut Type="9(008)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="21">
            <InfoCommon Niveau="10" Name="MyName2"/>
        </Attribut>
        <Attribut Type="9(006)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="22">
            <InfoCommon Niveau="10" Name="MyName3"/>
        </Attribut>
        <Zone OrdreZone="5" Redifinies="">
            <InfoCommon Niveau="10" Name="SC-CLESC."/>
            <Attribut Type="X(007)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="15">
                <InfoCommon Niveau="15" Name="MyName4"/>
            </Attribut>
            <Attribut Type="X(023)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="16">
                <InfoCommon Niveau="15" Name="MyName5"/>
            </Attribut>
            <Zone OrdreZone="6" Redifinies="">
                <InfoCommon Niveau="15" Name="MyName6"/>
                <Attribut Type="9(005)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="12">
                    <InfoCommon Niveau="20" Name="MyName7"/>
                </Attribut>
                <Attribut Type="X(011)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="13">
                    <InfoCommon Niveau="20" Name="MyName8"/>
                </Attribut>
                <Attribut Type="X(003)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="14">
                    <InfoCommon Niveau="20" Name="MyName9"/>
                </Attribut>
            </Zone>
            <Zone OrdreZone="7" Redifinies="">
                <InfoCommon Niveau="15" Name="MyName10"/>
                <Attribut Type="X(008)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="17">
                    <InfoCommon Niveau="20" Name="MyName11"/>
                </Attribut>
                <Attribut Type="X(017)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="18">
                    <InfoCommon Niveau="20" Name="MyName12"/>
                </Attribut>
                <Attribut Type="X(001)." Longueur="22" OrdreAttribut="19">
                    <InfoCommon Niveau="20" Name="MyName13"/>
                </Attribut>
            </Zone>
        </Zone>
    </Zone>
```

And i want convert to xmi

zone link with zone

Maybe xslt can do this ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just create a program to write line by line with the regle of XMI to get a file XMI. And I didn't find any lib which can do something like this